# 66 Transaction Process id was deadlocked on resources with another processand has been chosen as the deadlock victim rerun the transaction

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following VB Code which is inserting record in TRACK table. Also in the same time I am doing insert/update/delete in this tables CONTENT, COMNMENTRECORDED, NOTESASFILE, MASTER NOTIFICATION, DETAIL NOTIFICATION.

```
Dim Obj_trans As SqlTransaction = Nothing
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
If objcOnn.Initialize_cOnnection = True Then

                            cmd.Connection = objcOnn.cOnn
                            Obj_trans = objcOnn.cOnn.BeginTransaction
                            cmd.Transaction = Obj_trans
  If ForwadContent(intBasketID, 0, .SubItems(3).Text, str, _                                                              intBasketID, .SubItems(2).Text, .SubItems(4).Text, "Forward", Forward, Now.TimeOfDay.ToString, _                                                                    strComments, ContentState, Ascuflag, cmd, strAttachedFile) = True Then
                                                  dset_bsktUser = obj_notification.GetBasketUser(Forward, cmd)
                                        If Not dset_bsktUser Is Nothing Then
                                            'Update the DetailNotification 
                                            Dim SelUserid As String
                                            SelUserid = LoginUserID ' oLogin.ReadFromLogFile("UID")
                                            'what happen if forwarded by Administrator ?
                                            If obj_notification.UpdateDetNotification(3, CInt(lvView.Items(iSelected).SubItems(3).Text), CInt(SelUserid), 3, cmd) = True Then

                                                'Insert Into Master notification

                                                Dim id As Integer
                                                id = obj_notification.InsertMasterNotification(Forward, destibsktname, CInt(lvView.Items(iSelected).SubItems(3).Text), DocSNo, indexcardid, cmd)

                                                'now Insert the record into DetailNotification

                                                For i = 0 To dset_bsktUser.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                                                    Dim userid As Integer
                                                    userid = CInt(dset_bsktUser.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0))
                                                    obj_notification.InsertDetailNotification(id, CInt(userid), 0, 0, cmd)
                                                Next
                                            End If
                                        End If

                                    Else
                                        TransRolloback(Obj_trans)
                                    End If
                                End With

                            End If
                            lvView.Items.RemoveAt(iSelected)
                        End If 'End Connection
                        Obj_trans.Commit()
                        objcOnn.dispOse_cOnn()

Public Function CreateDocumentTrack(ByVal Sender As Integer, ByVal IndexCard As String, ByVal DocumentNo As Integer, ByVal Status As String, B

> Blockquote

yVal SentTo As Integer, ByVal SentTime As String, ByRef cmd As SqlCommand, ByVal lstview As ListView, ByVal listFiles As ListView) As Boolean
        Dim Ds_Track As New DataSet()
        Dim Da As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim TrackID As Integer = 0
        Try
            If oTableInfo.Exists(TBL_TRACK, SP_CREATE_TRACK_TABLE) = False Then Exit Function

            cmd.CommandText =  "Insert into TRACK (SENDER,INDEXCARDNAME,DOCUMENTnO,STATUS,SENTTO,SENTDATE,SENTTIME,nOTEid,uSERid) VALUES(@SENDER,@INDEXCARDNAME,@sTATUS,@sENTTO,@sENTdATE,@sENTtIME,@nOTEid,@uSERid)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@sENDER, SQLDBTYPE.INT,9, "SENDER").Value = Sender
                .Add("@iNDEXCARDnAME", SQLDBTYPE.NVARCHAR,75,"iNDEXCARDNAME").Value = IndexCard
                .Add("@dOCUMENTnO",SQLDBTYPE.INT,9, "dOCUMENTnO").Value = DocumentNo
                .Add("@sTATUS", SQLDBTYPE.NVARCHAR,25, "STATUS".Value = Status
                .Add("@sENTTO", SQLDBTYPE.INT,9, "SENTTO").Value = SentTo
            End With
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            'Get Inserted ID of Track 


           TrackID = CInt(Ds_Track.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0))

            'cmd.Dispose()
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()

            'Insert into Notes corrsponcding  with inserted trckid
            'INSERT INTO CommentRecorded    (TID, RID, TrackTag, BasketID, ContentID, UserName, ComDt, DocumentSno, IndexCardName, SourceTab)  VALUES     (,,,,,,,,,)
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CommentRecorded    (TID, RID, TrackTag, BasketID, ContentID, UserName, ComDt, DocumentSno, IndexCardName, SourceTab)  VALUES  (@TID, @RID, @TrackTag, @BasketID, @ContentID, @UserName, getDate(), @DocumentSno, @IndexCardName, @SourceTab)"
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@TID", SqlDbType.Int) ' .Value = TrackID
                .Add("@RID", SqlDbType.Int)
                .Add("@TrackTag", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
                .Add("@BasketID", SqlDbType.Int)
                .Add("@ContentID", SqlDbType.Int)
                .Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 75)
                ' .Add("@ComDt", SqlDbType.DateTime)
                .Add("@DocumentSno", SqlDbType.Int)
                .Add("@IndexCardName", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
                .Add("@SourceTab", SqlDbType.NVarChar)

            End With
            Dim sValues() As String
            Dim i, j As Integer
            For i = 0 To lstview.Length - 1

                If Not lstview(i) Is Nothing Then
                    If Not lstview(i) = "" Then
                        sValues = Split(lstview(i), "ç")

                        With cmd.Parameters
                            .Item("@TID").Value = TrackID
                            .Item("@RID").Value = sValues(8)
                            .Item("@TrackTag").Value = sValues(1)
                            .Item("@BasketID").Value = sValues(9)
                            .Item("@ContentID").Value = System.DBNull.Value '  sValues(8)
                            .Item("@UserName").Value = sValues(4)
                            '.Item("@ComDt").Value = Format(Now.Date, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
                            .Item("@DocumentSno").Value = sValues(11)
                            .Item("@IndexCardName").Value = sValues(12)
                            .Item("@SourceTab").Value = sValues(13)

                        End With
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


                    End If

                End If
            Next
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            'INSERT INTO NotesAsFile    (TID, AFID, TrackTag, BasketID, ContentID, UserName, ComDt, DocumentSno, IndexCardName)  VALUES     (,,,,,,,,)
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NotesAsFile    (TID, AFID, TrackTag, BasketID, ContentID, UserName, ComDt, DocumentSno, IndexCardName)  VALUES     (@TID, @AFID, @TrackTag, @BasketID, @ContentID, @UserName, GetDate(), @DocumentSno, @IndexCardName)"
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@TID", SqlDbType.Int) ' .Value = TrackID
                .Add("@AFID", SqlDbType.Int)
                .Add("@TrackTag", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
                .Add("@BasketID", SqlDbType.Int)
                .Add("@ContentID", SqlDbType.Int)
                .Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 75)
                '.Add("@ComDt", SqlDbType.DateTime)
                .Add("@DocumentSno", SqlDbType.Int)
                .Add("@IndexCardName", SqlDbType.NVarChar)


            End With


            For i = 0 To listFiles.Length - 1

                If Not listFiles(i) Is Nothing Then
                    If Not listFiles(i) = "" Then
                        sValues = Split(listFiles(i), "ç")
                        If sValues(0) <> "" Then
                            With cmd.Parameters
                                .Item("@TID").Value = TrackID
                                .Item("@AFID").Value = sValues(2)
                                .Item("@TrackTag").Value = "" ' sValues(1)
                                .Item("@BasketID").Value = sValues(4)
                                .Item("@ContentID").Value = System.DBNull.Value '  sValues(8)
                                .Item("@UserName").Value = sValues(6)
                                '.Item("@ComDt").Value = Format(Now.Date, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
                                .Item("@DocumentSno").Value = sValues(7)
                                .Item("@IndexCardName").Value = sValues(8)


                            End With
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End If

                    End If

                End If
            Next

            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            CreateDocumentTrack = True


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Rosetta")
            'oConn.DisposeConnection()
            'oMessage.DisplayException(ex.ToString)
            CreateDocumentTrack = False
        Finally
            Ds_Track.Dispose()
            Ds_Track = Nothing
            Da.Dispose()
            Da = Nothing
        End Try
    End Function


    Public Function CheckDocumentTrack(ByVal SentTo As Integer, ByVal DocumentNo As Integer, ByVal IndexCard As String, ByRef ContentState As Integer, ByRef cmd As SqlCommand) As Boolean
        Dim dset As New DataSet()
        Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        Try
            If oTableInfo.Exists(TBL_TRACK, SP_CREATE_TRACK_TABLE) = False Then Exit Function
            'Check that this already come from the basket or not
            cmd.CommandText ="Select Count(SENTTO) FROM TRACK" where SENTTO=@SENTTO AND DOCUMENTNO=@DOCUMENTNO AND INDEXCARDNAME=@INDEXCARDNAME
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@SeNTTO", SqlDbType.Int, 9, "sENTTO").Value = SentTo
                .Add"@dOCUMENTnO",SqlDbType.Int, 9, "dOCUMENTnO").Value = DocumentNo
                .Add("@iNDEXCARDNAME",SqlDbType.NVARCHAR, 75,"iNDEXCARDnAME").Value = IndexCard
            End With
            adp.SelectCommand = cmd
            adp.Fill(dset, "tRACK")
            count = dset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
            If count > 0 Then
                ContentState = 4
            Else
                ContentState = 1
            End If

            cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception

            oMessage.DisplayException(ex.ToString)
            Return False
        Finally
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            dset.Dispose()
            dset = Nothing
            adp.Dispose()
            adp = Nothing
        End Try

 Friend Function UpdateContent(ByVal approved As Integer, ByVal BasketID As Integer, ByRef cmd As SqlCommand, ByVal ContentID As String, ByVal Description As String, ByVal asu_Rec_flag As Integer, ByVal sender As Integer) As Boolean
        Try
            If oTableInfo.Exists(TBL_CONTENT, SP_CREATE_CONTENT_TABLE) = False Then Exit Function


            cmd.CommandText = "Update  CONTENT  Set BASKETID=@BASKETID, Description=@Description,Approved=@Approved,AssuReceivingFlag=@AsuReceivingFlag,FbkDate=getdate(),Sender=@Sender where ContentID=@ContentID
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@BASKETID",SqlDbType.Int, 9, BasketID).Value = BasketID
                .Add("@Approved",SqlDbType.Int, 9, aPPROVED).Value = approved
                .Add"@ContentID", SqlDbType.Int, 9, CONTENTID).Value = ContentID
                .Add("@Description", SqlDbType.nvarchar, 500, dESCRIPTION).Value = Server_Time_Content() & Description
                .Add("@AsuReceivingFlag", SqlDbType.Int, 9, AsuReceivingFlag).Value = asu_Rec_flag

                .Add("@Sender", SqlDbType.Int, 9).Value = sender
            End With
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()

            UpdateContent = True

        Catch ex As Exception
            oMessage.DisplayException(ex.ToString)

            UpdateContent = False
        Finally
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        End Try
    End Function


 Private Function ForwadContent( _
                        ByVal BskID As Integer, _
                        ByVal approved As Integer, _
                        ByVal ContentID As String, _
                        ByVal description As String, _
                        ByVal Sender As Integer, _
                        ByVal indexCardName As String, _
                        ByVal documentNo As Integer, _
                        ByVal Status As String, _
                        ByVal SentTo As Integer, _
                        ByVal SentTime As String, _
                        ByRef NoteID() As String, _
                        ByVal ContentState As Integer, _
                        ByVal ASU_Rec_FLAG As Integer, _
                        ByVal cmd As SqlCommand, _
                        ByRef listFiles() As String) As Boolean

        Try


            Dim Obj_trans As SqlTransaction


            If oTrack.CheckDocumentTrack(SentTo, documentNo, indexCardName, ContentState, cmd) = True Then
                approved = ContentState
                'If oContent.UpdateContent(SentTo, approved, cmd, ContentID, description) = True Then
                If Status = "Approved" Or Status = "Reject" Then
                    If oContent.DeleteContent(ContentID, cmd) = True Then

                    Else
                        TransRolloback(Obj_trans)
                    End If ' end if delete content
                Else
                    If oContent.UpdateContent(SentTo, approved, cmd, ContentID, description, ASU_Rec_FLAG, Sender) = True Then
                    Else
                        Try
                            Obj_trans.Rollback()
                            ForwadContent = False
                        Catch
                            MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Rosetta")
                        End Try
                        Obj_trans = Nothing
                        Exit Function
                    End If 'End if update content
                End If 'end if Approved/Reject



                If oTrack.CreateDocumentTrack(Sender, indexCardName, documentNo, Status, SentTo, SentTime, cmd, NoteID, listFiles, LoginUserName) = True Then
                    ForwadContent = True
                Else
                    Try
                        Obj_trans.Rollback()
                        ForwadContent = False
                    Catch
                        MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Rosetta")
                    End Try
                    Obj_trans = Nothing
                    Exit Function
                End If


            Else
                Try
                    Obj_trans.Rollback()
                    ForwadContent = False
                Catch
                    MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Rosetta")
                End Try
                Obj_trans = Nothing
                Exit Function
            End If
END IF
        Catch
            MsgBox(Err.Description)
        End Try
END FUNCTION
```

When I retrieve a record from TRACK table,

```
SELECT * FROM TRACK WHERE DOCUMENTNO=12 AND INDEXCARDNAME='ASD' ORDER BY TrackID
```

I will get this error sometimes(DEAD LOCK occurred ON TRACK),

```
66-transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-resources-with-another-process-and-has-been-chosen-as-the-deadlock-victim-rerun-the-transaction
```

[image]

ALL ABOVE TABLES HAVE NON-CLUSTERD ON AUTO GENERATED ID'S

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: i am getting deadlock exception when write, SELECT * FROM TRACK WHERE DOCUMENTNO=12 AND INDEXCARDNAME='ASD' ORDER BY TrackID

Comment: Yes you are.  Did you have a specific question about that?

Comment: @RBarryYoung, How to avoid this error? I am getting deadlock. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to try and get around this would be to change this:

```
SELECT * FROM TRACK WHERE DOCUMENTNO=12 AND INDEXCARDNAME='ASD' ORDER BY TrackID
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM TRACK (NOLOCK) WHERE DOCUMENTNO=12 AND INDEXCARDNAME='ASD' ORDER BY TrackID
```

There are downsides to this:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic177803-8-1.aspx

However, for the most part situations they will not come into play. This is a remedy for the problem rather than solving the underlying problem, without knowing what calls are made to your database and more about your data access in general that is going to be very difficult to do.